# Runtime Error NZEC on Hackerearth while running python3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

WHen I'm running the below code on hackerearth it's giving me Runtime Error NZEC.

```
t = input()
vow = ["A","a","E","e","I","i","O","o","U","u"]
while t>0:
    count_vow = 0
    str1 = input()
    for i in range(str1):
        if i in vow:
            count_vow += 1
    print(count_vow)
    t -= 1
```

Any sort help would be appreciated.

Comment: What input are you using? Whats the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Below is the input  
2  
nBBZLaosnm  
JHkIsnZtTL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first input you're expecting is a numerical value, so you should wrap your `input()` call in an `int()` so it stores this as a number

The 2nd problem you have is that you call `for i in range(str1)`, the `str1` is a string and using `range()` is for numbers. Just use `for i in str1:`

```
t = int(input())
vow = ["A","a","E","e","I","i","O","o","U","u"]
while t > 0:
    count_vow = 0
    str1 = input()
    for i in str1:
        if i in vow:
            count_vow += 1
    print(count_vow)
    t -= 1


Test Cases:
# >> denotes input and > denotes output

>> 2
>> nBBZLaosnm
> 2
>> JHkIsnZtTL
> 1
```